# How to override type of a base class member?

Tags: c++, class

I have the following hierarchy of class

```
class Boy : Child
class Girl : Child

class Parent
{
vector<Child> children;
}
class Anna : Parent
```

But I know before compilation that Anna will always only have boys, so instead of using only the Child interface of Parent , i'd like Anna to be able to access Boys members as well, it will be better for her children !
Is there anyway to model that without forcing a cast ?

```
class Anna : public Parent
{
vector<Boys> children; //Here i just    Hide the base class member
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Will you have several instances of the `Anna` class or should perhaps Anna be an instance of `Parent`? Also, should a person be able to be both a child and a parent in your model?

Comment: Yes i'll have multiple instance of Anna and yes, a person should be able to be a parent and a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a member of a base class change it's type depending on the derived type. However, you can make a template class with a dependent member and have your derived classes inherit a base of the desired type.

If you want the derived classes to have a common base, you can inherit the base template from a class.

```
class BaseParent {};
template<class T>
class Parent: public BaseParent {
    vector<T> children;
};
class Anna: public Parent<Boy> {};
```

Comment: I'll try and let u know

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of this

```
template <typename C> class Parent
{
    vector<C> children;
};

class Anna : public Parent<Boy>
{

};
```